# LoadError: Unable to autoload constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called `Conversation` in `app/models/conversation.rb` and a class called `Messages::Conversation` in `app/lib/messages/conversation.rb`.  When I try to call `Conversation` from console (expecting to get the model) it returns:

```
    [1] pry(main)> Conversation
    LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Conversation, expected .../application/app/lib/messages/conversation.rb to define it
    [2] pry(main)> Messages::Conversation
    => Messages::Conversation
```

I also have a model/class called `Message` similar to the above `Conversation`.  Since I am namespacing these, why is still looking for `Conversation` in my `Messages::Conversation` file instead of just `Conversation` in `app/models`?

Does it have something to do with having a `messages` folder and `Message` model?  If I rename `app/lib/messages/...` to `app/lib/messages_test/...`, everything works as expected.

Comment: try `::Conversation`

Comment: I tried that and got the same `LoadError: Unable to autoload...` error that it was looking in `messages/conversation`

Comment: Can you add the file paths and folders? I bet it's a problem with your file paths.

Comment: @chrisjacob what was the solution to this? I'm having the same upgrading to rails 5 but in happens only on a specific machine (CI).

Comment: @RaulA. I don't remember unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
Before

# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]

After

# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/models/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Check your config/application.rb and see if it works when you make these adjustments.  Not 100% sure if it will work.

Comment: The after is actually how my `autoload_paths` were set up before I ran into this problem.  Unfortunately, neither of those fixes it.